# Why does using ribbonReadTimeout don't break long request with Netflix Ribbon?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

We are using **Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE** with **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon** for our micro services. I set `ribbon.readTimeout=1000` for slow requests and check it with our micro service setting breakpoint inside `@GetMapping` method without sending a response. In my test I have been waiting for 10 minutes and did not get any exception. It seems like there is no readTimeout at all.

**Service configuration**

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 1000

my-service:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:8080
    ReadTimeout: 1000
    ConnectTimeout: 1000
```

The only way a can make it work is `ribbon.restclient.enabled=true`. But this client is deprecated and I don't wont to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all the ribbon properties are supported by spring-cloud-netflix while being used with a Spring `RestTemplate`. There are some ribbon properties that work, as described in the  [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html), but `ReadTimeout` is not one of them. So it does not work, but it's by desing (as per the response to this [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3231)). However, if you are using Spring's `RestTemplate`, you can set it there directly, like so:

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
        .setReadTimeout(2000)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I've set request timeout for RestTemplate and now it works fine.

Comment: @AlexeySaltanov I'm happy it was helpful. As it has solved your problem, could you please mark this answer as accepted and give it a +1?

Comment: I have tried setting this timeout property in my application.yml but got the message "Unknown property 'ribbon.ReadTimeout'". This way worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure Hystrix timeouts. Take a look at this part of the documentation : http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_hystrix_timeouts_and_ribbon_clients
It could be something like that :

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 1100
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 1000
  ReadTimeout: 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

We find this:

```
serviceA.ribbon.ReadTimeout=8000
```

work well with spring boot `2.1.0.RELEASE` using spring cloud `Finchley.SR2` and

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, we use ribbon via feign, in a client as so:

```
@FeignClient(value = "serviceA")
public interface ServiceAClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    String getTest();
}
```

We then use a wiremock test to introduce a fixed delay above the read timeout to verify it is working fine.